# Interpretations for Interaction-free measurements

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-measurements, locality, non-locality

So I read several papers on IFM by Vaidman, Dicke, and many others, In all of them I think the Pilot wave theory is able to adequately justify the observations, but then I came across several papers and other resources that this theory is wrong or incomplete to be more precise, So then in present times what is most acceptable and non-controversial interpretation to describe the observations of this experiment. Are there any local theories that are in the running or if there are non-local ones that could someone point heuristically in what sense they are non-local.

Comment: Are you interested primarily in thought experiments or actual experiments that have physically been conducted?

Comment: Thought experiments mainly.